# Motion in an adjustment layer in Premiere Pro

Tags: premiere

Is it possible to have motion, scale and position, that is, zooming in in parts of the video, in an adjustment layer in Premiere Pro? I tried it and it seems the effects I add to the adjustment layer from the list of effects apply to the video, but the motion changes don't. Am I doing something wrong?